# Error set datetime in php when using jquery plot?

Tags: php, jquery, plot, jqplot

I have a sample code:

```
<?php
$dateset = array();
$data[] = array("2013-08-22", 1);
$data[] = array("2013-08-23", 5);
$data[] = array("2013-08-24", 3);
$dataset = json_encode($data);
?>
<div id="data"></div>
```

And javascript

```
<script>
var dataset = [];
dataset = <?php echo $dataset; ?>;
var data = [{
    data: dataset,
}];
$.plot($('#data'), data, {
    series: {
       lines: {
          show: true
       },
       points: {
          show: true
       }
    },
    xaxis: {
       mode: 'time',
       timeformat: '%d/%m/%y',
       minTickSize: [1, 'day']
    }
})
</script>
```

Result not show plot, how to fix it ?

Comment: if you have that data static then why do not you directly add it into js code..?

Comment: @DipeshParmar: I using ajax jquery

Comment: well you did not put that code into question...so it's hard to understand it...

Answer (score 0):

You have `array` to `string` conversion. `$dataset` is an array and cannot print as a string.

```
dataset = <?php echo $dataset; ?>; // Notice: Array to string conversion
```

Try something like this:

```
<?php
$array_values = "";
foreach($dataset as $data){
    if($array_values != ""){
        $array_values .= ",";
    }
    $array_values .= $data;
}
?>

<script>
    var dataset = [<?php echo $array_values; ?>];
</script>
```